# BigQuery Web UI stuck "Loading BigQuery..."

Tags: google-bigquery

Tried logging into Web UI to run some queries this AM, UI never loads.

https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/welcome

Anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Same issue... Logged out, logged back in. Tried in incognito. Nothing seems to work. Probably a system outage at G.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you may be affected by a known issue. This is a high priority issue that Google is working to resolve as soon as possible. Here are some details about the issue:

Description:
We are currently investigating an issue with Authentication services.

Next update will be provided an update at 7:30 PDT.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I see the status message here now (wasn't there when I originally posted) https://status.cloud.google.com/